# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта, как исправить?

Tags: c#, json, .net

Мне приходит json я его инициализировала через свой объект и вытаскиваю значение:
`var name = Json.Client.Name;` но когда данного параметра в json'e нету я получаю ошибку "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта" что в полне логично, я инкупсулировала данный код в try catch но выглядит не эстетично...
как еще можно исключить ошибку в коде?

(.net4.7.2)

Как я понимаю можно использовать оператор as

```
var name = Json.Client.Name as string;
```

Но как быть со значениями int? он не может принимать null (ну как мне говорит компилятор)

Comment: `он не может принимать null`  - `int?` (внимание на знак вопроса). А да, если у вас `Name` - это то число, то строка, то вот это уже выглядит странно..

Comment: Интересная штука "?", не знала=)

Answer (score 2):

> но когда данного параметра в json'e нету

Значит проверяйте его наличие перед "вытаскиванием".

Comment: А как это лучше сделать?

Comment: @Liana вам стоит привести в вопросе более полный код того что вы делаете (например, вот тут что-то чудное сказано - *"json я инициализировала через свой объект"*)

Comment: jsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(response.GetValue().ToString())

Comment: @Liana вам стоит привести **в вопросе** более полный код того что вы делаете, а не тут в комментариях фрагменты )

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете присваивать дефолтные значения, если в объекте null

```
Console.WriteLine(Object.Name ?? "None" )
```

Что это означает? Вы можете в случае null присваивать объекту дефолтное значение

Comment: В данном случае я получаю ошибку, а не значение null

Comment: https://youtu.be/mXh0ci6O6og

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно, у меня не в переменной отсутсвует знаечение, а сама перменная...